# How can I keep a PyTorch submodule in eval mode?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pretrained model that I'm using in conjunction with a model being trained. I want the pretrained model to always be in eval mode, but the other model will be moving back and forth between eval and train mode. I'd still like the pretrained model to be a submodule of the other one, though (e.g. so that all parameters stay on the same device). Is there a way to do this? Here's a minimal example:

```py
from torch import nn

class FixedModule(nn.Module):
    pass

class TrainableModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, fixed_module):
        super().__init__()
        self.fixed_module = fixed_module

fixed = FixedModule().eval()
assert not fixed.training

trainable = TrainableModule(fixed)
assert trainable.training and not trainable.fixed_module.training

trainable.train()
assert trainable.fixed_module.training  # I'd like this to give an error
```

I know I can work around this by, e.g., always doing

```py
trainable.train()
trainable.fixed_module.eval()
```

but that's error-prone and doesn't work well with existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `train` in `FixedModule` to prevent it from changing modes. Note that `eval` just calls `train(False)`, so you don't need to override that too. But calling `FixedModule.eval` won't do anything now, so you have to set `training = False` in init.

```py
from torch import nn

class FixedModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.training = False

        # add any other nn.Module attributes here before calling self.children

        # you could override `train` in each child too if you really wanted,
        # but that seems like overkill unless there are external references
        # to any submodules of FixedModule
        for module in self.children():
            module.eval()

    def train(self, mode):
        return self

class TrainableModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, fixed_module):
        super().__init__()
        self.fixed_module = fixed_module    

fixed = FixedModule().eval()
assert not fixed.training

trainable = TrainableModule(fixed)
assert trainable.training and not trainable.fixed_module.training

trainable.train()
assert not trainable.fixed_module.training # passes
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to override `train` like this:

```
from torch import nn

class FixedModule(nn.Module):
    pass

class TrainableModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, fixed_module):
        super().__init__()
        self.fixed_module = fixed_module

    def train(self):
        super().train()
        self.fixed_module.eval()

fixed = FixedModule().eval()
assert not fixed.training

trainable = TrainableModule(fixed)
assert trainable.training and not trainable.fixed_module.training

trainable.train()
assert trainable.fixed_module.training  # This gives an error now
```

Comment: For some reason I wanted to avoid toggling train / eval for `fixed_module`, but I checked the source and `train` / `eval` just set a boolean flag (recursively on children), so there's no real reason to avoid that. Definitely upvoted, but I might accept my answer just because it would be nicer for `FixedModule` to handle this logic itself so no other classes have to worry about it.